# Как получить данные о другом пассивном приложении

Tags: данные

Язык - не важен. Нужно узнать данные о пассивном приложении (память, загруженность процессора и т.д.)

Стоит задача - узнать сколько оперативной памяти использует, например, Google Chrome и записать в базу данных.
Каким образом это можно осуществить или чем можно руководствоваться?

Comment: сегодня такой вопрос вроде бы уже был закрыт

Comment: Счётчики производительности (performance counter) помогут собрать любую информацию.